# Geo-blocking in Azure

Tags: azure, geoip

Is there any functionality available in azure out of the box to block access to a website or server from specific countries?  In a larger project that I'm involved with, we have an Imperva WAF and Palo Alto firewall that provide geo-blocking support.  However, the site in question is pretty small and couldn't support the added expense of these solutions.

Answer (score 3):

Azure websites don't have an geo filtering built in, however the Azure CDN provider does have [geo filtering](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cdn/cdn-restrict-access-by-country-akamai) so that might be something to look at. Still an extra cost, but not as bad as a WAF.

Answer (score 1):

A lot of config but you could use IPSecurity in the web.config and just block the CIDRs of whatever regions you don't want connecting.

https://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/security/ipsecurity

Get ranges and subnets from arin. Here is an example of APNIC (Asian Pacific)

https://whois.arin.net/ui/query.do

Comment: That works as long as the `web.config` stays under 250KB. Then you have to change a registry key, which you can't do on Azure Websites.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no such in-built functionality at the moment.

Comment: Upvote for knowing, that also a "no" answer is an answer.